# Rerun Failed test cases from output.xml using jython in robot/RIDE

Tags: robotframework, jython, atdd

I am using `RIDE 1.3` using `robotframework 2.8.7` running on `Python 2.7.6`. To execute my test I use jybot. The Jython version is `Jython 2.5.3`. I have an output XML generate from a previous run with failed cases. Now I need to selectively execute only the failed cases from the XML.

I have tried using the Command `-R --rerunfailed [xml_path]` by inserting it in the arguments tab of RIDE. But this command is unrecognised by the editor so I use `-R [xml_path]` instead which does not throw any errors.

Finally, when I start executing the suite I expect only the failed results from the suite to run but the entire suite runs as if the command has no effect. The suite from previous run and current run is same but the suite is large and `output.xml` generated is huge `(~100 MB)`.

How can I execute only failed cases?

Comment: Side note - you should upgrade **everything** in your environment; Robot Framework just got version 3.1 released, and 3.0 is 3 years old. Python's 2.7 is at patch version .11 for some time (and after exactly an year python2 will be EOL, in favor of 3). Staying with so old releases you risk hitting bugs fixed in the later versions, and - receiving no support from the community (I'm not saying this is the case for this situation, though; just - implying it ;) ).

Comment: Don't use both `-R` and `--rerunfailed ` simultaneously - they are synonymous, you should use one or the other. What happens when you run the command from the shell (the command line interface), not from RIDE?

Comment: @Todor I havent executed from shell. Will try doing it. Also I cannot really upgrade the environment

Comment: What is the result in shell execution?

Comment: It didn't work in shell either.